# cfinclude a .cfm of functions into a CFC, expensive?

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

Anyone knows how expensive would it be to `cfinclude` a .cfm of many functions into a CFC?

```
<cfcomponent>
  <cfinclude template="functions.cfm">
```

Or would it be faster if I attach functions to the object directly into its `This` scope?  (func1, func2 would be functions of the singleton Factory object).

```
<cffunction name="createX">
  <cfset x = new X()>
  <cfset x.func1 = func1>
  <cfset x.func2 = func2>
```

Which one is more efficient in terms of performance and memory usage?

Actually, how efficient is cfinclude?   Would the code be compiled on every include?

Comment: For common "lib" functions, you'd be better off putting them in a cfc in a persistent scope, eg. Application. Otherwise, with every cfc creation, the functions need to be copied into variables + this. It's only references, but still, more work on object creation.

Comment: Attaching functions into the `this` scope would break encapsulation for private methods(). It also wouldn't put them in the variables scope, so they couldn't call each other as expected, you'd have to run them as this.meth()

Comment: I strongly recommend against mixing cfinclude and CFCs http://cfbestpractices.blogspot.com/2012/05/avoid-using-cfinclude-within-cfc.html?m=1

Comment: I found injecting library into a CFC clumsy, also calling them requires the prefix of `someLib.someMethod()`, instead of just `someMethod()`.  That's why I'm exploring the idea of attaching lib function into the `this` scope.

Comment: @ShawnHolmes I used to do things in Java way and typed everything in CF, then I realized that I should really leverage the power of the scripting language such as decorate objects and mixin instead of rather static classes and  interfaces.  What we can't do in Java doesn't mean we shouldn't in CF.

Comment: I am using includes extensively for splitting large implicit controllers in FW/1 and CFWheels. Code is easy to read and edit in IDE (= maintain). Tried extending and injecting -- they provide no benefits over including for this specific task.

Comment: @Henry My response wasn't intended to direct you to do everything the Java way, it was to point out how early generation CF concepts are now commonly muddying the waters for present-day CF development because "..it just works so I'm going to go ahead and do it this way." Adam's response addresses this as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short response suitable for StackOverflow:

You need to remember that it's not the CFML that gets executed, so for performance considerations the more significant thing to look at is what ColdFusion actually executes, which is the compiled class files. And when compiling a CFC, CF creates one class for the CFC itself, and one class per method in the CFC. This is the same whether the methods are inline or included separately. The contents of the classes are slightly different, but not in a way that's meaningful as far as performance is concerned.

There are further considerations though, which favour - IMO - just putting the methods into the CFC.

Longer answer:
I've posted a larger analysis (which strays off-topic for your question, so not entirely suitable for here) on my blog, over [here](http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/which-is-better-having-your-methods.html)...

Answer (score 1):

You could place your functions.cfm contents into a functions.cfc and then use that in the Application scope.

Then in your CFC's you could just call `#application.functions.someMethod()#`

Or, perhaps your CFC's could "extend" the new functions.cfc and use its methods using the super way, like: `#super.someMethod()#`

I can't give you much info on performance, but caching wherever possible is always going to be best. I'd also strongly advise against including a `<cfinclude template="functions.cfm">` into your component...even if it appears to work, it's bad practice and could bring further issues.